# OSMF Media Player (implemented HLSPlugin) - Fullscreen Mode not working

Tags: flash, m3u8, osmf, http-live-streaming

I downloaded the OSMF Mediaplayer from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/osmf-media-player.html) and implemented the HLS Plugin (Hardcoded in source with `libs/HLSPlugin.swc`) to play HLS Streams and m3u8 Playlists.

However, once the Plugin is included the Fullscreen mode no longer works. If i switch to Fullscreen (while the Plugin is loaded) I just see a minimal small line of the movie playing, the line has full width but the height of the video is only 1 pixel.

If I remove the plugin and play the same MP4 video, the fullscreen mode works perfectly.  This only happens when I use fullscreen mode - if I resize the player in normal mode, it works normally.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

We saw this in our video player.  IIRC this was a bug with the Chrome PPAPI version of Flash *(or was it the Windows 8 native version?)*.  Adobe it fixed several versions ago.

So, please make sure you are running the [latest version of Flash](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).

Comment: Well i am on the latest version of flash... so its weird..

another thing i found out, on internet explorer only teh sound is playing and no video (btw. small pixel again also in normal mode on internet explorer)

on mozilla the video is fine in normal mode but just in fullscreen the video height is 1 pixel...

its totally weird...